# Newbie: Getting basic app script to work, encountered AppKey error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js) to get a basic appscript to work. When I load the given page ("quickstart.html"), it does properly prompt me to "authorize" the connection. After authorizing, it redirects me to an error page with the error:

```
[ORIGINAL ERROR] generic::not_found: com.google.apps.docs.error.DocumentNotFoundException: Invalid or missing required AppKey
```

The invalid/missing AppKey suggests that this is a basic configuration issue. Other than the html file itself, where else should I be looking to find how/where the "AppKey" is managed?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, figured it out. I had neglected to fill in the ENTER_YOUR_SCRIPT_ID_HERE variable. That was easy! :)